# Sum of elements of order $p$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2p^2\mathbb{Z})^\times$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

I have been working with the group $\mathbb{Z}/2p^2\mathbb{Z}$ and would like someone to correct my reasoning below.

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and consider the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/2p^2\mathbb{Z})^\times$. This group is cyclic, and so contains some element $c$ of order $|(\mathbb{Z}/2p^2\mathbb{Z})^\times| = \phi(2p^2) = p(p-1)$.

Now let $b = c^{k(p-1)}$ be an element of this cyclic group of order $p$ (i.e. $k \neq 0$). I am trying to find the value $1 + b + \ldots + b^{(p-1)}$ (mod $2p^2$). All equalities below are mod $2p^2$.

First, we let $A = 1 + b + \ldots + b^{(p-1)}$, and note that:
$A = b(b^{(p-1)} + 1 + b + \ldots + b^{(p-2)}) = bA$.
Similarly, we have $A = b^kA$ for all $k$, and therefore $A = 1 + b + \ldots + b^{(p-1)} = 0$ since $b^k \neq 1$, in general.

I know (from computing some examples numerically) that this is incorrect - I suspect that the sum is actually equal to $p$ mod $2p^2$ - but can't see where my reasoning is off. Any comments would be welcome.

Comment: The ring $\mathbb{Z}/2p^2\mathbb{Z}$ is not a domain, so $A = bA$ does not imply $A = 0$ if $b \neq 1$.

Comment: But if $A = b^kA$ for any $k$, can we not conclude something from that? If $A \neq 0$ wouldn't that imply $b^k = 1$ for all $k$, which isn't true since $b$ has order $p$?

Comment: No you can not, $A \neq 0$ does not imply $b^k = 1$ for all $k$ exactly because your ring is not a domain. To give an example with explicit $A$ and $b$ (not necessarily satisfying the other criteria in your question) in $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$: we can take $A = 2$ and $b = 6$ to find $A = bA$ hence also $A = b^k A$ for all $k$.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help. In this case, can anything at all useful be said about the value of $A$?

Comment: For now I can only notice that $A^2 = p A$, which brings you pretty close to the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are including $1$ in your sum, even though it has order $1$ and not $p$. That's fine though: given an odd prime $p$, define $A$ to be the sum of the elements of order dividing $p$ modulo $p^2$. You are correct that $A\equiv p\pmod{2p^2}$.

It's not hard to show that the elements of order $1$ or $p$ modulo $2p^2$ are
$$
1, 2p+1, 4p+1, \dots, 2(p-1)p+1.
$$
Indeed, we know there are exactly $p$ such elements (since the multiplicative group is cyclic); and
$$
(2kp+1)^p = \sum_{j=0}^p \binom pj (2kp)^j \equiv 1 + p\cdot2kp  + \sum_{j=2}^p 0 \equiv 1\pmod{2p^2},
$$
so this list must be complete. (Alternately, use the fact that elements of order $p$ modulo $2p^2$ are precisely the $(p-1)$st powers, and any such integer must be congruent to $1\pmod p$ by Fermat's little theorem.)

From here we easily compute that $A = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} (2kp+1) = p^2(p-1)+p\equiv p\pmod{2p^2}$.

Comment: Both answers were helpful, but thanks for the calculations. I'm taking away from this that I need to remember to consider the actual elements as well as just the abstract properties of the group.

Answer (score 1):

One can explicitly find an element of order $p$ in this group, namely $b = 2p + 1$. Then it is not hard to compute
$$
A = 1 + b + \ldots + b^{p - 1}
$$
modulo $2p^2$.